# Graph Theory Question On Exam Involving colorability of certain planar graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

I had a question on my exam and answered it using what I believe to be an **Exhaustive Proof**. The teacher marked it wrong, and while I understand there is a simple answer to the question, I would like to understand why my answer is wrong. The question is as follows:

**Prove or disprove - A planar graph with 8 vertices and 13 edges can be 2 vertex colorable.**

My answer:

A graph has a vertex coloring of 2 if and only if it is bipartite, and since the graph in question is planar, than it can not contain the subgraph k<sub>3,3</sub> and the complete subgraph k<sub>5</sub>. This leaves the only possible bipartite graph with 8 vertices as k<sub>1,7</sub> and k<sub>2,6</sub>, which both don't have 13 edges (used a table to show this). C<sub>8</sub>, which is bipartite does have 8 vertices but only 8 edges, and a tree with 8 vertices cannot have 13 edges. This proves that no matter what configuration of a planar graph with 8 vertices and 13 edges, it can not be 2 vertex colorable.

Would appreciate your thoughts, comments and criticism.

Thanks.

Comment: I have thought about your problem and I think you are right.

Comment: A planar graph cannot have $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ as a *minor*. They do not need to be subgraphs. For example, consider adding a vertex to $K_5$ so as to split one of the edges in two. The resulting graph does not contain $K_5$ as a subgraph, but as a minor. See the [Wikipedia article on minors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor).

Comment: @Théophile then doesn't that even strengthen my argument?

Comment: @royherma Indeed. You're right up to the point where you say that it can't contain the subgraph $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ (N.B. $or$, not $and$.) But the following sentence has a mistake: you say that "This leaves only ..." and list a few possibilities, but in fact there are many(!) more bipartite graphs on 8 vertices. For example, what about trees? (They wouldn't have enough edges, but still, you must consider them.)

Comment: @Théophile I actually did write about trees! - its in the second to last sentence. What other bipartite graphs are there either than trees, regular bipartites, and circuits?

Comment: @royherma Oh, I see. I thought your sentence ended earlier (there's a period in there that should be a comma). Still, you're missing many graphs: for instance, consider adding an edge to a tree such that the resulting cycle is even.

Comment: @Théophile Wouldn't that create a cycle and thus not be bipartite -> not two colorable...

Comment: @royherma If the cycle is even, then of course the graph would still be 2-colourable. To put my last example in different words, start with a tree that has been two-coloured, then add an edge between a black and white vertex. The result is a planar graph that is (in general) not a tree, a regular bipartite graph, or a circuit, yet is clearly 2-colourable, since we have provided a colouring by construction where no two adjacent vertices have the same colour.

Answer (score 1):

Your cases are not exhaustive.  You can still have a subgraph of $K_{4,4}$ that is planar and is not a subgraph of $K_{1,7}$, $K_{2,6}$, or $C_8$.  Think, for example, of the graph of a cube.  Also, you seem to be confusing edges and vertices.  The question asks for a graph with $8$ vertices and $13$ edges, but you seem to be talking about graphs with $8$ edges.

While the statement is correct; a planar graph cannot have $8$ vertices and $13$ edges, a better approach is to use Euler's formula.  Let $G$ be a planar graph with $8$ vertices and $13$ edges.  Without loss of generality, $G$ is connected, so $v + f - e = 2$ (assuming $G$ is connected).  This gives us $f = 7$.  Now if $G$ is $2$-colorable, then every face has at least $4$ edges on it.  So we can  "recount" the vertices: we have $7$ faces, each with at least $4$ edges on them, and each edge appears in at most two face.  So $e \ge 7 \cdot 4 / 2 = 14$, a contradiction.

Comment: But if it has k4,4 as a subgraph, then it has k3,3 which makes the whole graph not planar, thus it does not match the characteristics of the graph at question...

Comment: Sorry, corrected my mix up with vertices and edges - should make more sense now.

Comment: I believe that I left out hypercubes,cubes and median graphs - if I would have add them to the exhaustive proof I think my answer would be correct..

Comment: @royherma The difficulty with this sort of exhaustive proof is that you need to *prove* that these comprise all the cases.  This would be quite difficult, and there would be too many cases to cover.  It is almost always easier to look for general methods like the one above.

Comment: I absolutely agree, but on the test I did not remember the specific formula that was the correct and short answer, so I tried to use logic to explain why it isn't possible.